# Why pytorch has two kinds of Non-linear activations?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, activation-function

Why pytorch has two kinds of Non-linear activations?

[image]

Non-liner activations (weighted sum, nonlinearity): 
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#non-linear-activations-weighted-sum-nonlinearity

Non-linear activations (other): https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#non-linear-activations-other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference is that the functions listed under *Non-linear activations (weighted sum, nonlinearity)* perform **only thresholding** and **do not normalize** the output. (i.e. the resultant tensor *need not* necessarily sum up to 1, either on the whole or along some specified axes/`dim`ensions)

Example non-linearities:

> nn.ReLU
>   nn.Sigmoid
>   nn.SELU
>   nn.Tanh

---

Whereas the non-linearities listed under *Non-linear activations (other)* perform ***thresholding and normalization*** (i.e. the resultant tensor sums up to 1, either for the whole tensor if no axis/`dim`ension is specified; Or along the specified axes/`dim`ensions)

Example non-linearities: (*note the normalization term in the denominator*)

> [image: softmax]
>   [image: softmin]

However, with the exception of `nn.LogSoftmax()` for which the resultant tensor doesn't sum up to 1 since we apply log over the softmax output.